# Adding a value to a dictionary in python?

Tags: python, dictionary, pycharm

I have a basic menu program below. I am having trouble with adding the 'price' of the item to the final "orders" dictionary so that the "txt" file created shows the item and price appropriately.
In the code, you can see that the "orders" is not a dictionary at the moment, but is a 'list' (this is the only way I can get it to work at the moment. Also, I have a hard coded "3.00" for the price instead of the actual value of the item that the person selects (I know I need to replace that "3.00" with something else). Thanks for your help in advance...

```
def print_menu(menu):
    for name, price in menu.items():
        print(name, ': $', format(price, '.2f'), sep='')


def get_order(menu):
    orders = []
    order = input("What would you like to order? (Q to Quit)")

    while order.upper() != 'Q':

        found_boolean = menu.get(order)
        if found_boolean:
            orders.append(order)

        else:
            print("Menu item does not exist")
            order = input("Anything else? (Q to Quit)")

    return orders


def total_bill(orders, menu):
    total = 0

    for order in orders:
        total += menu[order]

    return total


def write_sales_log(orders, total):
    sales_log = open('sales.txt', 'a')

    for item in orders:
    sales_log.write(item + ' ' + format(price, ' .2f') + '\n')
    sales_log.write('total = ' + format(total, '.2f') + '\n\n')
    sales_log.close()


def main():
    menu = {'Roast Beef': 2.5, 'Hot Dog': 3.0, 'Hamburger': 3.5}  
    print_menu(menu)
    orders = get_order(menu)
    total = total_bill(orders, menu)
    print("You ordered:", orders,
          "Your total is: $", format(total, ' .2f'), sep='')
    write_sales_log(orders, total)


main()
```

Comment: This would be easier to read (and answer) with correct whitespace and short, non-trailing comments (or better: remove all the comments!).

Comment: Please explain what you want the final dict to look like. At what point do you want to add a value to it?

Comment: I'm sorry for the poor description of the issue. Thank you for the comments

Comment: Thanks Mateen Ulhaq, I removed the comments (didn't realize I had so many in there)

Answer (score 0):

Here's a few things to work on.

First, in this code:

```
found_boolean = menu.get(order) 
   if found_boolean:
        orders.append(order)
```

it appears that you are misundertanding what the `get` function does.  It looks up a key in a dictionary, and returns the associated value.  It does not return a boolean.  If you just want to see if the `order` is one of the keys in the `menu` dictionary, then try this:

```
if order in menu:
    orders.append(order)
```

Second, see how in the `total_bill` function you correctly wrote `menu[order]` to lookup the `order` in the `menu` dictionary and get back the associated value (the price)?  Use that same syntax to get the price for each item in the `write_sales_log` function.  So, for example:

```
for item in orders:
    price = menu[item]
    sales_log.write(.......
```

Third, in the `get_order` function, you only ask the user for another order if their first order was invalid.  If they give you a valid order, then your code goes into an infinite loop and gets stuck.  You probably want to move the `order = input("Anything else? (Q to Quit)")` line outside the `else` block.

Fourth, you wrote that you wanted `orders` to be a dictionary.  As you point out, currently that variable holds a list.  Why would you rather that it hold a dictionary?  If you would rather use a dictionary, then how would that dictionary be structured?  A dictionary associates keys with values (like your dictionary `menu` that associates food items with their prices).  What would the keys and values of the `orders` dictionary be?  As it is, it looks perfectly reasonable for `orders` to continue to be a list.

Comment: Thanks @Andrew Merrill, I appreciate the detailed comments and will apply these thoughts to my code. I'm learning python and trying to get better